# Disjunctive simplification

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

What is this rule of inference called?

$(P\wedge Q)\vee(P\wedge\neg Q)\vdash P$

My (silly) motivation is [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14157/5051).

Comment: I think that the name you have used is correct; the rule Peter Smith applied in his proof is called *conjunction elimination*, but also *simplification* : see [Simplification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplification)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Yours is, technically, the only attempt to answer my question! Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome ! :)

Comment: Distributive conjunctive elimination.

Comment: Distributive conjunction simplification.

Comment: Distribution conjunction out.

Answer (score 3):

Someone down voted dtldarek's answer, but his principal claim is plainly correct:

In a natural deduction system, start with the premiss:

> $(P \land A) \lor (P \land B)$

then argue by cases (an intuitionistically acceptable mode of reasoning):

> $\quad|\quad (P \land A)$
>
> $\quad|\quad P$
>
> $\quad/$
>
> $\quad|\quad (P \land B)$
>
> $\quad|\quad P$

Since we get to the same conclusion either way, we can discharge the two temporary assumptions and conclude

> $P$.

Hence we have $(P\wedge A)\vee(P\wedge B)\vdash P$ whatever the $A$ and $B$, and so have $(P\wedge Q)\vee(P\wedge\neg Q)\vdash P$ as a special case. The special case doesn't depend on the law of excluded middle.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the law of excluded middle (i.e. this is true in intuitionistic logic too). In fact even a stronger statement is true:

$$(P \land A) \lor (P \land B) \to P$$

and you can prove it by the distributive law and projection (i.e. $P \land Q \to P$):

\begin{align}
(P \land A) \lor (P \land B) &\to P\\
P \land (A \lor B) &\to P \\
P &\to P
\end{align}

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Why downvote?$ $

Comment: zso now enough upvotes again:)

Answer (score 1):

It can be justified by distribution and the law of the excluded middle: $Q\lor \lnot Q \equiv T$:

$$(P \land Q)\lor (P \land \lnot Q) \equiv P \land (Q\lor \lnot Q) \equiv  P$$